# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:flutterBuildDebug' when start vscode flutter debugging

Tags: java, android, gradle, visual-studio-code, flutter

This is my environment: OS: Linux Mint 19 Tara Cinnamon 64bit (based on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.10.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

This error appears in debug console when I click `Debug > Start Debugging` in Visual Studio Code.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script '/home/ilhamwahabigx/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 602
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: E:\\flutter\\.pub-cache\\hosted\\pub.dartlang.org\\collection-1.14.11\\lib\\collection.dart

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: does `E:\\flutter\\.pub-cache\\hosted\\pub.dartlang.org\\collection-1.14.11\\lib\\collection.dart` path exist? I'm not sure that path exist within linux normally

Comment: @selharxets actually, i'm using dual boot and that was my windows 8.1 path. In linux that should be `/media/ilhamwahabigx/Work/flutter`. I just been realize why it reference there

Comment: some IDE config files and SDKs should not be shared between OS. You should reinstall SDK and omit any User/OS-specific config files

Comment: that's the weird thing, I had separate my config and SDKs. I wonder where I missed it

Answer (score 7):

You need to run `flutter clean` first. Then run your app with this command `flutter run`. This works for me, I hope to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using MacOs, what worked for me was upgrading flutter `flutter upgrade --force` and restart android studio, if not worked you can try changing flutter channel to master and re change it to stable